# How to get value from website using Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to extract href title `<a href="https://kwejk.pl">43797</a>` so I could assign it to variable in my app. My code is not working unfortunatelly.

I want to assign "43797" to string Result.

Answer (score 1):

You've selected `li` tag
Now you need to get first his child and then get text

```
    Elements liChildren = element.children();
    Element first = liChildren.first​();
    String res = first.text();
```